# How to handle Dynamic xpath in Groovy?

Tags: xpath, groovy

in the below example the xpath had been in given in the code.

```
String xml = Recall.getXml()
def telephoneNumbers = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)​​​​​​​​
def outputBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String telephoneXml = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield telephoneNumbers.telephone }
```

would like to know any possible solution to specify the same xpath through a variable. like below.

```
String telephoneXml = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield ${xpath} }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to be clear this is not `xpath`. in groovy it's named [gpath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath), and it's a groovy expression.

You can use [Eval](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) class to evaluate groovy expression from string:

```
def xml = '''<root>
  <telephone>1234567899</telephone>
  <cell>1234567890</cell>
</root>'''
def telephoneNumbers=new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def outputBuilder = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def gpath = "xml.telephone"
String telephoneXml = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield Eval.me('xml',telephoneNumbers,gpath) }
```